# Can't understand the way the function is summing up numbers

Tags: python

I see it as `y=4+(3*0)=4` then `y=4+(3*1)=7`. But where is the 13 coming from `y=4+(3*2)=13`?

```
x=3
y=4

for i in range (10):
    y=y+x*i
    print(y)
```

Comment: `y` is not `4` any more. `y=7+(3*2)` is `13`.

Comment: the value of `y` is being changed for every iteration

Comment: First iteration has `y=4+3*0` (4). Second iteration has `y=4+3*1` (7). Third iteration has `y=7+3*2` (13).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`y` changes on each iteration. So the value substituted into `y + x*i` also changes.

```
y = 4 + (3*0) = 4
     ___________|
    ↓
y = 4 + (3*1) = 7
     ___________|
    ↓
y = 7 + (3*2) = 13
     ___________|
    ↓
y = 13 + (3*3) = 22

...
```

Answer (score 1):

y is constantly changing and after i is 1 is being changed to 7.

you need to put y = 4 in your for loop as well.

```
x=3

for i in range (10):
    y=4
    y=y+x*i
    print(y)
```

or better change the result variable:

```
x=3
y=4

for i in range (10):
    a=y+x*i
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

First loop : 
*i = 0* : 
y = 4+(3*0) = 4

Second loop : 
*i = 1* : 
y = 4 +(3*1) = **7**

third loop : 
*i = 2* : 
y = **7** + (3*2) = 13